# My desktop with conky appears to stack up on itself

Tags: conky, visual-artifacts

I recently downloaded Conky and I'm very satisfied with it however there is one issue that I cannot seem to figure out. My conky appears to stack up on itself, and it looks very distorted and weird. This isn't something that happens when it first starts, but that happens over time.

I have attached an image of before it stacks, and an image of around 5-10 minutes later. I'm not sure if its stacking every minute or not.

```
# Conky settings #
background yes
update_interval 1
double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

# Window specifications #
gap_x 0
gap_y 40
alignment top_right
minimum_size 600 360
maximum_width 600
own_window yes
own_window_type override
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
#own_window_argb_visual yes
#own_window_argb_value 0
#border_margin 0
#border_inner_margin 0
#border_outer_margin 0
```

This code is the only section I edited, in which I changed the gap to fit my screen, and changed

```
own_window_type normal
```

to

```
own_window_type override
```

in order to have complete transparency instead of the shadow.

[image: BEFORE]

[image: AFTER]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  I had to change `own_window` to be `no`